# Remove characters from start and end of ' + e.link[0].href + '?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, youtube

I've looked through all the stuff to remove characters from strings but I don't understand what's going on here.

I'm using a [jQuery script](http://danhounshell.com/blog/add-a-youtube-widget-to-any-web-site-with-jquery/) to get videos from a Youtube channel and it displays them with links to the video. On the same page I've embedded a video using the [iframe code](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html). I set the videos to open in the target which is the iframe. However the URLs don't work.

- URL it should be: http:// www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID
- URL it currently is: http:// www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID&feature=youtube_gdata

(Broken links because new users can't post more than 2 links)

I need to remove the extra so what I wanted to do was remove `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=` from the start and `&feature=youtube_gdata` from the end then add `http://www.youtube.com/embed/` back to the start.

However the link seems to be some sort of event and I just couldn't work out how to do it.

```
 + e.link[0].href +
```

The above is how the link appears in the javascript.

How can I make the link I need from this?

Thanks very much,
Jack Clarke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the video id out of the old URL and construct a new URL like this:

```
var origURL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayYNAEs0few&feature=youtube_gdata";
var matches = origURL.match(/(&|\?)v=([^&]+)/);
var newURL = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + matches[2];

// newURL == http://www.youtube.com/embed/ayYNAEs0few
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zwcgL/.

Using this technique of extracting the actual video ID from the original URL, you can then construct any type of other URL that uses it with some simple string addition.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably an easier way to do what you want to do, but a really quick way would be to do something like:

```
var link = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12345678";

link.replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','');

// link now = 12345678
```

So you could use that to append to a string.

```
link2 = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + link;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var original = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID&feature=youtube_gdata";
 var changed = original
                 .replace( "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/")
                 .replace( "&feature=youtube_gdata", "");

 alert( changed ); // shows "http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID"
```